# In ∆ABC, AB=AC, $\angle A = 80°$, find angles of ∆AXY

Tags: geometry

So the question is,

In a triangle $ABC$, $ AB=AC$, $A=80°$ and $S $ is circumcentre. Bisectors of angles $ACS$ and $ABS$ meet $ BS$ and $ CS$ at $X$ and $Y $ respectively. find angles of $∆AXY$ I found all the angles till the very last $∆AXY$ is left but then I'm not able to find any way of calculating any angle further. I found out all the similar triangles but it's not helping. I'm attaching my worked out image below:

[image]

My workings:
$\angle BAC$=80°, $\angle  BSC=160°$, $BS=BC$, Thus, $\angle SBC=SCB=10° $
$\angle ABS=ACS=40°$, $∆BSX $is congruent to $∆CSY$ and both of them are isosceles with the base angles of $20°$

$P$ is the point of intersection of $AS$ and $XY$. $∆XSP$ and $∆YSP$ are congruent, thus angle $XPS=90°= $$\angle APX $
$∆APX $is congruent to $∆APY$.
I don't know now what to do. Some insights would be helpful.

Comment: I am not very sure how you proved that $BSC = 160$. Could you add details please?

Comment: S is the circumcentre, and A also lies on the circle. So inscribed angle theorem

Comment: That's fair. Thank you

Comment: The figure is completely symmetric. Look for congruent triangles. It turns out to be an equilateral triangle.

Comment: I know that the two triangles are congruent but this just means that $\angle AXP = \angle AYP$ and $\angle YAP = \angle XAP$...which just gives $\angle AXP + \angle YAP = 90°$

Comment: @Ruchi You can find more angles in the figure. $\bigtriangleup BSX \;\text{and} \bigtriangleup CSY$ are both isosceles. So: $\measuredangle SXY=\measuredangle SYX =10°$ We get that $BXYC$ is an isosceles trapezoid. In fact, if we prove that, $\bigtriangleup BAX \cong \; \bigtriangleup BYX $ we would be done.

Comment: I have actually calculated all the angles except of the ∆AXY. What you have commented I already came across, but it's not helpful for finding the main angles . And I did realised that all I need now is to find how side SC = AC for which the two triangles BAX and BYC can be proved congruent but I'm unable to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Triangle ABC]

The figure is symmetric so knowing $\angle BAX$ will do the work.

The problem can be differently worded as follows :

In $\triangle ABC$, $AB=AC$ and $\angle A=80^{\circ}$. $X$ is a point inside the triangle for which $\angle XBC=30^{\circ}$ and $\angle XCB=20^{\circ}$. Find $\angle  BAX$.

Let the circumcentre of $\triangle BXC$ be $O$.

Observe that,  $\triangle BOC\cong \triangle BAC$ and $\triangle OXC$ is equilateral from angle chasing. Hence, $\triangle XAC$ is isosceles and thus $\angle BAX=10^{\circ}$.

Comment: How is $\triangle BOC\cong \triangle BAC$ ? The angles are all different as per my calculations in the diagram

Comment: And Point X, O(the circumcentre) and C are supposed to be collinear then how can ∆OXC be a triangle? (In my diagram, S is the circumcentre instead of O)

Comment: @Ruchi $\triangle BOC\cong \triangle BAC$ because they are both isosceles with $AB=AC$ and $OB=OC$,  share the common side $BC$ and $\angle BOC=80^{\circ}=\angle BAC$.

Comment: @Ruchi The points $X$, $O$ and $C$ are not collinear. $O$ is the circumcentre of $\triangle BXC$